# Should i release return object from CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex call?

Tags: objective-c

It's not stated in documentation for `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` function. But am i right that i should call `CFRelease` on retured `CFDictionaryRef` ?

Quick sample:

```
NSDictionary* metadata = (NSDictionary   *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
......................
//Should i call CFRelease(metadata); ??
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should release it.
It doesn't say it in the documentation because it's a general convention. Every object returned by a function with `Copy` or `Create` in its name is owned by you and should be released when you're done.

Comment: thanks, i was just confused that many CGImageCreate functions state it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

For GC, you can do this too:

```
(NSDictionary *)NSMakeCollectable( CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(sourceRef, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options) );
```